# PHP/MySQL efficient way to spot specific pattern in data

Tags: php, mysql

I have an arduino grabbing outside light level from an LDR at 1 minute intervals. I am therefore storing the the data for each day as a time series dataset with a percentage light and a timestamp. The data looks like below (although is stored in a mysql db) and produces this graph:

{"Timestamp":"2017-03-22 14:48:48","ExternalLight":"99.5"},{"Timestamp":"2017-03-22 14:47:46","ExternalLight":"99.6"},{"Timestamp":"2017-03-22 14:46:44","ExternalLight":"99.8"},{"Timestamp":"2017-03-22 14:45:42","ExternalLight":"99.8"},{"Timestamp":"2017-03-22 14:44:40","ExternalLight":"99.8"},{"Timestamp":"2017-03-22 14:43:38","ExternalLight":"99.8"},{"Timestamp":"2017-03-22 14:42:36","ExternalLight":"99.8"},{"Timestamp":"2017-03-22 14:41:34","ExternalLight":"99.7"},{"Timestamp":"2017-03-22 14:40:32","ExternalLight":"99.6"},{"Timestamp":"2017-03-22 14:39:30","ExternalLight":"99.5"},{"Timestamp":"2017-03-22 14:38:28","ExternalLight":"99.5"},{"Timestamp":"2017-03-22 14:37:26","ExternalLight":"99.6"},{"Timestamp":"2017-03-22 14:36:24","ExternalLight":"99.6"},{"Timestamp":"2017-03-22 14:35:22","ExternalLight":"99.8"},{"Timestamp":"2017-03-22 14:34:20","ExternalLight":"99.8"},{"Timestamp":"2017-03-22 14:33:18","ExternalLight":"99.8"},{"Timestamp":"2017-03-22 14:32:16","ExternalLight":"99.7"},{"Timestamp":"2017-03-22 14:31:14","ExternalLight":"99.6"},{"Timestamp":"2017-03-22 14:30:12","ExternalLight":"99.5"},
.......
[image]

I am looking for the most efficient way to identify the two specific changes - where it gets light in the morning, and where it gets dark in the evening. Would it be possible to do this using a MySQL query? Or will I need to select all of the data and process it using PHP? I am not really sure the best way to start so I am looking for some guidence!

Many thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that this is a data analysis problem and neither MySQL nor PHP are good fits.  I generally wouldn't suggest trying to do something like this in PHP.  I seriously doubt it is even possible in MySQL.  A language that is designed more for data analysis and processing would work much better.  Personally, I use python for these kinds of tasks, which has excellent tools like numpy/scipy/matplotlib.  What did you make your plot in?  If that is an actual programming language, that might be a good choice.

The thing to do is to figure out the algorithm that you will use to measure these things, and then figure out how to implement that algorithm in your language of choice. The reality is that the question you are asking is much more complicated than it might seem at first glance.  Taking a time series and building a algorithm to reliably extract information like "sunrise" and "sunset" can be surprisingly involved, especially when you account for things like variable weather conditions, etc.  This is probably a fairly straight-forward problem to start with, but what you really need (from the sounds of it), is not help selecting a technology (i.e. MySQL or PHP), but help building an actual algorithm.  This may or may not be the best place for that.  Have you done any data analysis before?